# Why is Raspberry Pi smbus2 message length inconsistent?

Tags: i2c

**Question:** How can I stream out the whole buffer as a continuous i2c transaction, instead of it being broken up like this?

**Background**

I am driving an SSD1306 OLED using SMbus2.
The display takes a 1024 byte message to write every pixel on the screen. Writing a small amount of text to the screen, I can see that the i2c transactions behave differently for

- **A)** the top part of the screen, which is *blank*
- **B)** the middle of the screen, which contains text
- **C)** the bottom part of the screen, which is blank

Referring to the images below, data streams as one continuous block for blank portions of the display - just as you would expect.
For portions of the screen with text however, the data is broken up into *single byte* transactions - slowing everything down considerably. This is crippling the framerate.

[image: Sections A and C of the frame buffer - continuous data]
[image: Section B, where there is text]

The relevant call to smbus is as follows, where buf is a 1024B bytearray

```py
i2c.smbus_i2c_write(addr, reg, buf, len(buf))
```

I've tried regressing to different i2c drivers eg.  `"dtoverlay=i2c-bcm2708"` in `boot/config.txt`.
Curiously, when I attempt to manually chunk into 32byte transactions and send with write_block_data() it's actually worse - working with 1byte transactions for the whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

The SMBus protocol imposes a maximum message size of 32 bytes.

The function named `smbus_i2c_write` is presumably using the I2C protocol which has no such limit.

I don't use the smbus module and have no idea how it behaves.

You could use an alternative I2C implementation.  E.g. my [pigpio Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module allows for 1024 bytes buffers for I2C transactions.

Use [i2c_write_device](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_write_device).

Comment: I've come across pigpio in my travels before - perhaps it's about time I ditch smbus and port my project over to pigpio. Thanks for your suggestion @joan - I'll keep you posted :)